# How to change commit message of one of previous commits in Git?

Tags: git

I would like to change the commit message one of my previous commits. I guess I can

- return to the commit I would like to amend with `git reset <the commit id>`,
- change the commit with `git commit --amend` and
- return back with `git reset <my last commit id>`.

Unfortunately it did not work. After `git commit --amend` I do see the message changed but after `git reset <my last commit id>` I see the old unchanged commit message.

How can I change the commit message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `rebase`

- `git rebase -i <commit id>^` - Opens up a list of commits on your your `$EDITOR`. The caret at the end of the line is needed, since you need to specify the *parent* of the commit you want to edit.
- Change the line `pick <commit id>` to `reword <commit id>`, save and close the file.

  > r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
- It will immediately re-open and load up the specified commit. Edit the message and save.
- Note that this **will change all subsequent commid ids**! As with all other git objects, commit hashes are computed from its contents, and that includes the commit message.

Furthermore, you should understand the implications of rewriting history if you amend a commit that has already been published.
 For more information regarding `rebase` see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History and https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

---

### Why `git reset` doesn't work

IMHO, the intesting part of this question is examining why your initial attempt did't work as expected. Basically it boils down to this: **Commit objects are inmutable**.

`git reset B` makes the branch point to a specific commit:

```
A -- B -- C -- D
     ^
```

`git commit --ammend` creates an alternate timeline:

```
A -- B -- C -- D
 \
  *- E
     ^
```

By moving back to the future with `git reset D`, the changes you made are discarded.

```
A -- B -- C -- D
 \             ^
  *- E
```

Comment: This latter plan will work, but instead of `git reset D`, and supposing your branch at D is called `foo`, go `git rebase --onto E B foo`